# How to use minitoc with babel-hungarian?

Tags: babel, minitoc

I'm trying to use the minitoc package in a document with babel (Hungarian). This is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage[hungarian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}
\mtcselectlanguage{hungarian}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\minitoc
\section{Sub-introduction 1}
\section{Sub-introduction 2}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\minitoc
\end{document}
```

This works perfectly, but if I uncomment `\usepackage[hungarian]{babel}`, the minitocs disappear without any error message.

(Note: `\mtcselectlanguage{hungarian}` has no effect on the end result.)

This is completely mysterious as there is not even a warning. I have no idea where to start debugging. I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

**EDIT:** I've tested this with `\usepackage[english]{babel}`, and it worked, so it looks like the problem is with the Hungarian babel option.

**EDIT 2:** Setting `classmod=unchanged` as @schtandard suggested, resulted in incorrectly formatted chapter/section/etc. headings (as expected). I could fix this using the titlesec and tocloft packages:

```latex
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}
\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{.}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.\ \chaptertitlename}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}
```

This restored the correct Hungarian format.

Comment: The style for Hungarian does lots of tricky things. The manual (in Hungarian) is here: https://math.bme.hu/latex/magyarldf-doc.pdf . Search for `defaults=safest`.

Comment: @JavierBezos thank you! This makes the minitoc's appear but the chapter/section/etc. name and numbering scheme becomes English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be a combination of the `classmod` and `extra` options. (I wasn't able to determine the exact interaction yet. Maybe if I have time later.) Adding either

```latex
\PassOptionsToPackage{classmod=unchanged}{hungarian.ldf}
```

or

```latex
\PassOptionsToPackage{extras=no}{hungarian.ldf}
```

before `\usepackage[hungarian]{babel}` will result in the `minitoc`s being shown. If in doubt, I would go for `classmod`.

Comment: Thank you! The minitocs appear now but the chapter and section headings are formatted differently (which is expected of course but not good). What was "1. fejezet" before becomes "fejezet 1". But I think this can be solved by redefining headings using the titlesec package.

Comment: I solved the problem I mentioned in my previous comment with the combination of the tocloft and titlesec packages. Thank you again for taking the time to look into this.